# Study the existence of the partial derivative and differential.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x^{1010}y^{1012})}{x^{2020} - y^{1010}x^{1010} + y^{2020}} & \text{if } (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\
0 & \text{if } (x, y) = (0, 0)
\end{cases}$$

Hey! I have this function and have to study the existence of partial derivatives and differential in point (0,0). Have tried multiple ways but can't figure out a way to solve.

As I know from theory , i have to study the limit in point (0,0). Tried that by assuming that x = y from the second equation and replaced in the first to get:  $$\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{{\sin(x^{2022})}}{{x^{2020}}}$$
From this point I don't know what to do. Can someone give a hint?

Comment: $\sin(x^{2022}) / x^{2020} = (x^2) \sin(x^{2022}) / x^{2022}$

Comment: Use L'Hopital or $sin(x)\approx $x for small x

Comment: Since $\lvert \sin(y) \rvert \leq \lvert y \rvert$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, your limit is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a u-sub
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^{2022})}{x^{2022}}$$
Let $u = x^{2022}$, Note that as $x$ approaches $0$, $u$ also approaches $0$
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}$$
This limit is well known

Comment: it's 2022 power at sin and 2020 power down, can't do U sub

Comment: @Valentin so make the denominator be $x^{2022}$. Surely you can make an algebraic manipulation to achieve that.